# Telerik WPF - TreeMap Select item programatically

Tags: wpf, telerik, treemap

Is it possible to select an item programatically? After I bind the TreeMap control I would like to select a default item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Set the `IsSelectionEnabled` property to `true` and then set or bind the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` property to an item in the `ItemsSource` like you would do with any other `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I have tried your approach but is not working, if I try to set the SelectedItem I get an error message: RadTreeMapBase.SelectedItem is read only. I can set the SelectedValue property, but even when I see that SelectedValue has the correct value, visually I do not see the item selected.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreemap/selection), `SelectedItem` gets or sets the selected item.

Comment: I saw the same, I don't know if it has something to do with my version of the control, but I think I found the issue, I was using an ObservableCollection as ItemsSource, now I change that to use a List, then I set the SelectedValue property and I can see the item selected in the control.